# Does Dividing Gender Is A Role Or Job Of Data Scientist

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, data-science

My Question is bit theoretical and i have debate in certain conference . Does dividing the gender is a role of data scientist or not ? . In My point of view I think it is a role of data scientist because he will be able to find out the maximum number of sales done by any gender what is the age of the gender who are using particular e-commerce website . what are their interests etc ?

Need help regarding this

If we further look into analytics tools like **Alexa and google analytics** they even provide the percentage of users according to their gender and their interests?

further more google introduced new business intelligence tool.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an on-topic question as defined by the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (in short SO is focused on specific code problems, and is not a discussion board).

Comment: then where I should post this question?